# Let $\left\{ H_i | i \in I\right\}$ be a family of subgroups of G. State and prove a condition which makes $\cup_{i \in I} H_{i}$ a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, cyclic-groups

> Let $G$ be a group and $\left\{ H_i | i \in I\right\}$ be a family of subgroups of G. State and prove a condition which makes $\cup_{i \in I} H_{i}$ a subgroup of $G$, that is that $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i} = \left< \cup_{i \in I} H_{i} \right>$.

To show that $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i} \subseteq \left< \cup _{i \in I} H_{i} \right>$, it seems that I have to show that $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i}$ is a subgroup of G. Since  $\left< \cup _{i \in I} H_{i} \right>$ is a collection of subgroups of G that contain  $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i}$ as a subset, I would have the first inclusion proven and quite possibly get the second inclusion for free.

However, I am having a hard time on how to prove $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i}$ is a subgroup of $G$. The only way this could happen is the collection of subgroups $\{ H_{i} | i \in I\}$  is a chain.

Is there another way to show that $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i}$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Comment: Yes, you are right that chaining is the only way this can happen.  Try first just thinking about two subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$.  The way you wrote your reasoning though is very convoluted and confusing.  I'll just say that $\cup _{i \in I} H_{i} \subseteq \left< \cup _{i \in I} H_{i} \right>$ is the trivial direction.  You want to show that anything in the generated subgroup is already in the union, i.e. the reverse direction.

Comment: @norfair although chaining surely gives a positive result, we only need the $H_i$ to be 'directed' in some sense. For example, if for all $i,j$ we have $k$ with $H_i,H_j \subset H_k$, this is enough to prove that the union is closed with respect to multiplication, and weaker than having a partial order with respect to inclusion.

Comment: Yes, my mistake.  It doesn't have to be a total ordering.  I'm confused why you say it's weaker than partial order though.  Isn't that exactly the characterization?

Comment: @norfair My bad. I meant to say that 'directedness' suffices but we get anti-symmetry for free as the order in defined by inclusion, which is a partial order on $\mathcal{P}G$ and it is weaker than having a total order (i.e. a chain).

Comment: @norfair note that however it is not enough for the groups to be partially ordered. Even if we take two groups $H_1, H_2$ , it may very well be that $H_1 \cup H_2$ is not a subgroup.

Comment: yes...so what is the word for this simple condition then? Surely there is one :)

Comment: I guess there needs to be a greatest element?

Comment: I am unaware. Strictly speaking, I am almost sure that the condition is equivalent to having a function $k : G^2 \to I$ such that $gh \in H_{k(g,h)}$, but I don't think this is any more useful that the original situation. If we allow to lose the equivalence, then in my answer I have included a somewhat natural partial result.

Comment: I think your condition "for all $i$,$j$ we have  $k$ such that $H_i,H_j \subset H_k$" is equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87443/discussion-between-guido-a-and-norfair).

Comment: @overachiever Again, another friendly admonishment to not pick useless titles. I've edited this one for you too.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, it seems like the condition is of your choosing. You are on the right track when thinking about a collection of 'chained' groups. I would advise you to try and prove this for a countable collection $G_1 \subset G_2 \dots$. This could lead you to stronger results which only use the essentials of the previous proof.

A sketch of a possible generalization is below,

> Suppose that $(H_i)_{i \in I}$ is such that for each $g \in H_i, g' \in H_j$ there exists $k \in I$ with $g,g' \in H_k$. Then, the set $H = \bigcup_{i \in I} H_i$ is a subgroup of $G$: clearly we have that $1 \in G$; and if $g \in H_i \subset H$, then $g^{-1} \in H_i \subset H$. So far we have used no assumptions. Now, take $g,g' \in H$. Hence there exist $i,j \in I$ with $g \in H_i$ and $g \in H_j$. By hypothesis we have $k \in I$ with $g,g' \in H_k$ and so $gg' \in H_k \subset H \ \square$.